# How to prove this integral converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$$\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,{\rm d}x$$

So far i tried to use the comparison test with $\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}$ but i noticed that it's not always true. any ideas?

Comment: What James is saying is that if you know that $\sqrt{x} > \ln(x)$ for $x \ge b$ then it is enough to show that the integral $$\int_b^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} dx$$ is convergent, since we know already that $$\int_{1}^b \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} dx$$ is convergent.

Comment: Joel has it. Frequently when you do comparison texts (for integrals and series) the thing you are comparing with won't always be bigger (or smaller) but as long as there is some point after which it is always bigger (or smaller) you can make the comparison because the little bit at the beginning doesn't change convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} < \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2} $$

and using integration by parts

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx = 1.$$

By comparison $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
=\overbrace{\bracks{{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
+\int_{1}^{0}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over 1 + 1/x^{2}}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}}}
^{\ds{=\ 0}}\
+\
\bracks{\overbrace{-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{=\ G}}}
$$
$\ds{G \approx 0.9160}$ is the
[Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)
and the remaining integral is a well known representation of $\ds{G}$ as reported in the above link.

> $$
> \color{#77f}{\large\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x = G}
> \approx 0.9160
> $$

Comment: He asked for a proof of the convergence, not evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can show that $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}$ is *bounded above* on our interval, you can conclude convergence. And it is not hard to show that in fact $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{1/2}}=0$.

Actually, in our interval, $\sqrt{x}$ is **always** $\gt \ln x$. Let $f(x)=x^{1/2}-\ln x$. We have $f(1)\gt 0$. By using the derivative, you can show that $f(x)$ reaches a minimum at $x=4$. Since $f(4)\gt 0$, it follows that $\sqrt{x}\gt \ln x$ for all $x$ in our interval.

Answer (score 0):

Make the change of variables $u=\ln(x)$
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} =  \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{ue^u}{1+e^{2u}}.$$

Now when $u$ close to zero the integrand behaves as $u/2$ which is integrable function. Try to finish the problem.

**Added:** Here is another hint

$$ \frac{ue^u}{1+e^{2u}} \leq \frac{ue^u}{e^{2u}}= ue^{-u} $$

which is integrable function (you can use integration by parts) over $(0,\infty)$.